# Setup XStream to set object value to null if a certain attribute is present

Tags: java, xstream

I am receiving notifications in xml format from a third party system and trying to parse them with XStream.

Notification sent from third party system looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<account>
  <phone1>unknown</account_code>
  <phone2/>
  <phone3 nil="true"/>
</account>
```

An our java representation of the notification looks like this:

```
public class Account {
  private String phone1;  
  private String phone2; 
  private String phone3;
}
```

Out of the box XStream parses `phone1` and `phone2` as expected, but `phone3` is of course also parsed to an empty string.

Is there a neat way to make XStream understand that when `nil="true"` that the value should be set to null?

Comment: Great example XML covering 3 different cases. First end-tag mismatches, might be a typo: `<phone1>unknown</account_code>`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom converter like explained in:

- [XML mapping attribute of nested element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425401/xml-mapping-attribute-of-nested-element)

#### Custom Converter to parse attributes

Implement a custom `Converter` like this:

```
public class PhoneNilableConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object o, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        // implement logic for marshalling to xml
        if (o == null) {
            writer.addAttribute("nil", "true");
        } else {
            writer.setValue(o.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        String phone = "";  // default phone value

        if ("true".equals(reader.getAttribute("nil"))) {
            phone = null;
        } else {
            phone = reader.getValue();
        }

        return phone;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class cls) {
        return cls == String.class;
    }
}
```

Then add the converter to your field with annotation `@XStreamConverter` like this:

```java
public class Account {
  private String phone1;  
  private String phone2; 
  @XStreamConverter(value=PhoneNilableConverter.class)
  private String phone3;
}
```

Next you can test and make sure to enable XStream to `processAnnotations` for this class:

```
XStream xs = new XStream();
xs.processAnnotations(Account.class); // required to make XStream aware of annotations

Account a = (Account) xs.fromXML(
  "<account>\n" +
  "  <phone1>unknown</phone1>\n" +
  "  <phone2/>\n" +
  "  <phone3 nil="true"/>\n" +
  "</account>");
System.out.println(a);
```

See also:

- [XStream and parse xml attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34206426/xstream-and-parse-xml-attributes)